# Use NewRelic for my Apache Storm Project?

Tags: apache-storm, newrelic

I want to monitor my server instance where i have storm process running. How can i use **new-relic** in my Apache Storm Projects.

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I seem to find about this is related to some kind of "kafka plugin". Not sure if that is what you're looking for: http://newrelic.com/plugins/convertus/230

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add instrumentation for your Storm topology :

1) Include the new relic agent api dependency to your topology code. For example :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
 <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
 <version>${newrelic.version}</version>
 <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

2) Add your @Traces etc. (ie Spout nextTuple(), Bolt execute() etc)

3) Package your code ready for submitting to Storm. (But don't do it yet)

4) Install the newrelic.jar and your edited version of newrelic.yml to the Storm Supervisor servers (Just the supervisors as we will only instrument the Workers)

5) make sure the logs directory under newrelic.jar is writable by the Worker processes.

6) Edit the Storm Supervisor's storm.yaml configuration file (STORM_HOME/conf/storm.yaml)
 - Add or include the following, using your newrelic location : (depending if you already have a worker.childopts setting)

```
worker.childopts: "-javaagent:/opt/storm/newrelic/newrelic.jar"
```

7) Kill any running Topologies. Restart the Supervisors. Submit your Topology(ies) again. Watch the storm supervisor log, you should see the normal New Relic log output :

```
com.newrelic INFO: New Relic Agent: Loading configuration file "/opt/storm/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a language supported by a New Relic agent, you should be able to monitor it. It may be necessary to use custom instrumentation if the monitors are not getting enough insight out of the box.